# I get the "The specified solution configuration is invalid" in DevOps Pipelines even though the configuration appears valid

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

The exact error is:

> ##[error]D:\a\1\s\node_modules\deasync\build\binding.sln.metaproj(0,0): Error MSB4126: The specified solution configuration "**Azure-Dev|AnyCPU**" is invalid. Please specify a valid solution configuration using
> the Configuration and Platform properties (e.g. MSBuild.exe
> Solution.sln /p:Configuration=Debug /p:Platform="Any CPU") or leave
> those properties blank to use the default solution configuration.

But my solution does contain that exact configuration, exactly as spelled, spaces and all:

```
GlobalSection(SolutionConfigurationPlatforms) = preSolution
    Azure-Dev|Any CPU = Azure-Dev|AnyCPU
    Debug|Any CPU = Debug|AnyCPU
    Integration|Any CPU = Integration|AnyCPU
    localdev-iis-sql|AnyCPU = localdev-iis-sql|AnyCPU
    Release|AnyCPU = Release|AnyCPU
EndGlobalSection
```

I've seen similar issues reported on SO, but it's usually a misspelling, missing configuration, or a missed space or something. But unless I'm not seeing clearly, the configuration specified in the error is the exact same in my solution config. I had realized that originally, my solution showed "Any CPU", while my project showed "AnyCPU." I changed the solution config to remove spaces to match the project, but the issue persists.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: I just realized that this was against the binding.sln solution file under node_modules. I can add SkipInvalidConfigurations=true to the build solution step to ignore this error, but is that an acceptable fix? Is there anything I can do from npm to fix this?

Comment: Post the details of your pipeline + tasks and refine the details of your question because at present it is too vague.